# JavaBean documentation

Tags: java, javabeans, javadoc

I've been messing with making custom controls in Java, and I'm wondering what the proper way to add documentation is. I've got lots of private variables with getters and setters, and each variable has it's own PROP_[variable name] variable. I'm specifically looking for the way to document them that would show up in the Netbeans editor when you hover over the variable (like with a JLabel, if you hover over the text property, it reads "Defines the single line of text this component will display").

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've tried multiple locations for the javadoc, and none of them seem to work (yes, I am generating the javadoc). I've put docs on the private field, the PROP_[variable name] field, and the getters and setters, and none of them have worked. I've also tried looking in the BeanInfo file, and there's nothing relating to javadoc there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. In the generated BeanInfo class, you can set the "short description code" property to a string, and that is what shows up. There's actually no javadoc inside of the code file itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple: add comments (`/**` ... `*/`) on top of the item you want to add docs for. Full example:

```
/**
 *Defines the single line of text this component will display
 */
public class JLabel{
   ...
}
```

This text will be shown when your mouse hovers over the item. Refer to this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) for a complete picture on documentation.

Comment: I guess I should have been a bit more clear. I meant WHAT part do I put the comment on. Do I put it on the private variable? Do I put it on the getter/setter? Do I put it on the PROP_[variable name]? I understand how Javadoc works, just not for this specific usecase.